# How do I check if a given datetime object is "between" two datetimes?

Tags: python, django, datetime, time

```
my_event = Event.objects.get(id=4)
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

How do I do check if my current time is between them?

```
my_event.start_time < current_time < my_event.end_time
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your answer is the way to go as long as start_time and end_time don't have an associated tzinfo class. You can't directly compare a naive datetime with a timezoned-datetime.

Answer (score 12):

you can use a simple if comparing three dates, like this

```
if date1 < yourdate < date2:
  ...do something...
else:
  ...do ...
```

Answer (score 3):

I know old, but since this is so high on Google results, answers here don't take into consideration two cases:

1. If your time equals either of your range, ie your range is 6-8 and it is 6.
2. If your time range is say 18:00 to 6:00, valid range; however 19:00 would not match.

I wrote a function to take care of time comparison, hope this helps anyone viewing this old question.

```
def process_time(intime, start, end):
    if start <= intime <= end:
        return True
    elif start > end:
        end_day = time(hour=23, minute=59, second=59, microsecond=999999)
        if start <= intime <= end_day:
            return True
        elif intime <= end:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

The datetimes getting tested need to all naive (no timezone) or all aware (timezone). An exception should occur if you try to compare aware and naive. If all the datetimes are aware the timezones don't actually have to match that appears to be taken into consideration when comparing.

e.g.

```
class RND(datetime.tzinfo):
    """ Random timezone UTC -3 """

    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return datetime.timedelta(hours=-3)

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return "RND"

    def dst(self, dt):
        return datetime.timedelta(hours=0)


april_fools = datetime.datetime(year=2017, month=4, day=1, hour=12, tzinfo=pytz.UTC)

random_dt = datetime.datetime(year=2017, month=4, day=1, hour=9, tzinfo=RND())

random_dt == april_fools
# True as the same time when converted back to utc.

# Between test of 3 naive datetimes
start_spring = datetime.datetime(year=2018, month=3, day=20)
end_spring = datetime.datetime(year=2018, month=6, day=21)
april_fools = datetime.datetime(year=2018, month=4, day=1)


if start_spring < april_fools < end_spring:
    print "April fools is in spring"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my script of checking the time between two different timeslots. One for morning and one for evening. This is the extended script using @Clifford's script

```
def Strategy_Entry_Time_Check():
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    #current_time = current_time.replace(hour=13, minute=29, second=00, microsecond=00) #For testing, edit the time
    morning_start = current_time.replace(hour=9, minute=30, second=00, microsecond=00)
    morning_end = current_time.replace(hour=11, minute=00, second=00, microsecond=00)
    evening_start = current_time.replace(hour=13, minute=00, second=00, microsecond=00)
    evening_end = current_time.replace(hour=15, minute=00, second=00, microsecond=00)
    
    if morning_start <= current_time <= morning_end:
        print("Morning Entry")
        return True
    elif evening_start <= current_time <= evening_end:
        print("Evening Entry")
        return True
    print("No Entry")
    return False
```