# how is checking dates in C#

Tags: c#

i have 2 dates : **date1** and **date2** ; I want to check is that another date is between date1 and date2 thanks very much

Comment: Re: The current answers, unless you know the order of `date1` and `date2`, you'll want to sort that out before comparing it to `anotherDate`'.

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672862/check-if-datetime-instance-falls-in-between-other-two-datetime-objects

Answer (score 6):

You can just use the standard <, >, >= and <= operators:

```
if( someDate >= date1 && someDate <= date2 )
{
}
```

And, you can make your own extension method for it:

```
public static class DateExtensions
{
    public static bool Between( this DateTime d, DateTime start, DateTime end )
    {
        return d >= start && d <= end;
    }
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
DateTime someDate = new DateTime (2012, 5, 6);

if( someDate.Between (date1, date2) )
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's simple:

```
if (date3 >= date1 && date3 <= date2)
```