# Searching list for value that meets criteria

Tags: python

I've got a list of datetime objects (key) and number of events that occur at those times(value). We'll call this the time_list.

Let's assume that I also have the following variables (these are also datetime objects):

datetime1 = Jan 1, 2019, 6:30PM

datetime2 = Jan 1, 2019, 8:30PM

What's the most efficient way to determine if there are any entries in the list that are > datetime1 and < datetime2?

I've used a for loop to loop over the items and then break when I find a match, but I'm wondering if there is something more efficient.

Thanks!

Comment: Which ways did you try (and found out that aren't as efficient as expected)?

Comment: A dictionary isn't good for this task. It's better to use a sorted list where you can do binary search.

Comment: Interesting. I'll try that.

Comment: You can use an ordered dict to get the first date by using a hash lookup and then search the next dates in linear fashion, until you get to the end.

Comment: Someone above just said a dictionary isn't good for this and I should use a list, which I've implemented, but I"m not sure how to most efficiently search it. At the moment, I'm looping through each item in the dict until I get a hit and then I'm breaking out of the for loop.

Comment: Do you break the loop after a single hit? So you'll get only one element, not all the elements that satisfy the criteria. Or I misunderstood?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if datetime instance falls in between other two datetime objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672862/check-if-datetime-instance-falls-in-between-other-two-datetime-objects)